# How to avoid returning None from an iterator?

Tags: python, iterator, generator

I am trying to write an iterator that gives the leap years in the given time period. It returns the values as expected but additionally returns None which I do not wanted to be returned.

This is my code.

```python
class year:
    def __init__(self,start,end):
        self.start = start
        self.end = end
    def __iter__(self):
        return self
    def __next__(self):
        value = self.start
        if self.start < self.end:
            if value%4 == 0 and (value%100 !=0 or value%400 == 0):
                self.start+=4
                return value
            else:
                self.start+=1
        else:
            raise StopIteration
y = year(2009,2115)
yiter = iter(y)
for i in y:
    print(i)
```

It gives the following output.

```
====== RESTART: C:\Users\Admin\AI-and-ML-practice\py programs\leapYearWithIterator.py ======
None
None
None
2012
2016
2020
2024
2028
2032
2036
2040
2044
2048
2052
2056
2060
2064
2068
2072
2076
2080
2084
2088
2092
2096
None
None
None
None
2104
2108
2112
>>>
```

Expected output

```
2012
2016
2020
2024
2028
2032
2036
2040
2044
2048
2052
2056
2060
2064
2068
2072
2076
2080
2084
2088
2092
2096
2104
2108
2112
>>>
```

Comment: Well, unless you happen to start on a leap year, all that happens when calling `__next__` is `self.start+=1`. You need to keep calling `__next__` until you hit a leap year, then your iterator will start returning values. Obviously you’ll need to change that so it finds the first leap year itself internally and *always* returns a value from `__next__`.

Comment: If a Python function finishes execution without an explicit `return` statement, then `None` is returned to the caller. That's happens with your `__next__` method just like any other function or method.

Answer (score 1):

A more efficient approach would be to start from the year closest to the given starting year that's greater than or equal to the starting year and is divisible by 4, and then add 4 to it for each iteration for a potential leap year. If the potential leap year is divisible by 100 and is not divisible by 400, then it isn't really a leap year, and we'll just need to add another 4 to it to make it a leap year:

```
class LeapYear:
    def __init__(self, start, end):
        self.next = (start + 3) // 4 * 4
        self.end = end

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        value = self.next
        if value % 100 == 0 and value % 400 != 0:
            value += 4
        if value >= self.end:
            raise StopIteration
        self.next = value + 4
        return value
```

Demo: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZFBS8QwEIXv/RXPg9C6xW3dCq4Q74I3T55KcKdsoKQhmRX99XVaYzaL5pDDvDffzEvcFx8nu3twfp7fRx0CXki7N9L@sYCcAw3oe2MN930ZaBxqBNaea5A9VD@e5SzSraVPhkK5OrDBrsJ2iw436C6N0is@uYt8CJOPQzKwJz55u7bl5mXUX/OHHk8k5LRNUswQxWu0TQOl0EDLFr/FTopXUjyzzryNyvZPoCeVslw2eW0C4ZUn9yyJNJvJ/vtMEZ6xY9ZVKIph8jAwNv1I2e73XY27tr2PmZ03lktTzfM3)

Answer (score 1):

Your inner `else` doesn't have an explicit return, so it returns `None` by default. Smallest fix would be to just add `return next(self)`:

```
            else:
                self.start+=1
                return next(self)
```

Btw if you just want some iterator for iteration, I'd use a generator instead of a class:

```
def year(start, end):
    start += -start % 4
    for y in range(start, end, 4):
        if y % 100 or not y % 400:
            yield y
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your next logic into a while True loop.

```
def __next__(self):
    while True:
        value = self.start
        if self.start < self.end:
            if value%4 == 0 and (value%100 !=0 or value%400 == 0):
                self.start+=4
                return value
            else:
                self.start+=1
        else:
            raise StopIteration
```

Answer (score 0):

I have made some modifications to your code and it is working.

```
class Year:
    def __init__(self, start, end):
        self.start = start
        self.end = end

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        value = self.start
        while value <= self.end:
            if value % 4 == 0 and (value % 100 != 0 or value % 400 == 0):
                self.start = value + 4  
                return value
            value += 1

        raise StopIteration

y = Year(2009, 2115)
yiter = iter(y)

for i in y:
    print(I)
```

[image: Desired Output]

Answer (score 0):

**You can try this way:**

```
class Year:
    def __init__(self, start, end):
        self.start = start
        self.end = end

def __iter__(self):
    return self

def __next__(self):
    while self.start <= self.end:
        value = self.start
        if value % 4 == 0 and (value % 100 != 0 or value % 400 == 0):
            self.start += 4
            return value
        else:
            self.start += 1

    raise StopIteration


year = Year(2009, 2115)

for i in year:
    print(i)
```

**And the output looks like**

[image]

**I coded it in W3school python codebase.**